# Customizer: Update Preview instantly when typing into a number input field

Tags: theme-customizer

Im working on some customizer settings for my theme. Im using chrome. I created a number input field:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'st_opacity',
   array(
      'default' => '100',
      'type' => 'theme_mod',
      'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
      'transport' => 'postMessage',
   ) 
);      
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control(
   $wp_customize,
   'st_opacity',
   array(
      'label' => 'Opacity (%)',
      'section' => 'sitetitle_options',
      'settings' => 'st_opacity',
      'type' => 'number',
      'input_attrs' => array('min' => '0', 'max' => '100'),
      'priority' => 41,
   )
) );
```

The preview updates under 2 circumstances:
- When I use my arrow keys while the number field is selected.
- When I type into the number field and then click outside of it.

I want the preview to update while I'm just typing into the number field. How can I do that?

When I use a normal text input, it updates the preview instantly. But with a number input, it works differently.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('input[type="number"]', window.parent.document).on('keyup', function(){
           window.parent.jQuery(this, window.parent.document).trigger('change'); 
        });
    }, 0);
});
```

Use [customize_preview_init](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/customize_preview_init) to enqueue this js.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the this behavior is due to the underlying `wp.customize.Element` not being updated to be aware of the HTML5 input types, though the more underlying reason is that it needs to be listening to `input` events instead of the current approach of deciding whether to use `change`, `keydown` or other event handlers. All should now get updated to use `input` only since that is standard and we don't have to worry about IE incompatibility anymore. See [#35832](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/35832). Long story short, this should be fixed in a minor release of WordPress relatively soon.